# Big O, Omega and Theta Notation Properties

Tags: asymptotics

As an exercise, we have to prove or disprove certain statements about the properties of Big O Notation.

I struggle with two of those right now.

1. "For all $a,b \in N, a \le b: n^{\frac{1}{a}} \in \Theta(n^{\frac{1}{b}})$."

Is the first one correct? I have to prove that:

$c*n^{\frac{1}{b}} \le n^{\frac{1}{a}} \le s*n^{\frac{1}{b}} $

holds true for every every a and b. I think that you can always find a c small and a s big enough.. but how do I prove it?

2. "There are different functions f and g, so that $f \in \Omega(g)$ and $g \in \Omega(f)$."

The second one is true, right? Essentially I have to prove that for $f(n) \neq g(n)$ that

$c*g(n)\le f(n)$ and $s*f(n) \le g(n)$

holds for some functions true, so I have to find just one and I proved it.
I'd say for example $f(n)=n^2+1$ and $g(n)=n^2$.
So $c=1$ and $s=\frac{1}{2}$ for example.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 2 is correct, 1 is not true.

Comment: For instance, take $a=1$ and $b=2$. You have $\sqrt{n} \leq n$, so $\sqrt{n} = O(n)$. But you do not really have $n = O(\sqrt{n})$... (since $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$)